# executing bash script file from php

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to call a bash script from my php file of click of a button that simple creates a directory. However, when i run from the web it would not do anything when i run from the terminal it works fine.

Not sure what the problem is ?

test.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$result =shell_exec('sh /var/www/shellscriptphp/test.sh ');
exit();
```

test.sh

```
mkdir testfolder
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the whole "path" to `mkdir` command in your `test.sh`

Comment: Make sure the webserver userid has permission to create things in the destination folder.

Comment: Why not use PHP functions for creating directories? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: You don't need to call a shell script to create a directory from php.  That said, you should check the perms of your shell script

Comment: Thanks a lot guys indeed there was permission errors. This was just a sample code i do a lot more than that due to which i am not using php functions to create directories.

Comment: [PHP](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) + Bash to create directories on a web request. \*Shudder\*

Comment: Be carful! The Shellshock and Aftershock bash security vulnerabilities can exploit scripts like these.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the question, your code works as long as your uid has permissions on the server's filesystem.

You can change permissions in the filesystem using `chmod` (see `man chmod` for details).